# Dynamically changing a session variable in php?

Tags: php

I have tried searching the site before posting and not finding anything about this. Forgive me if I am mistaken. What I am doing is making a calendar system. Each day is populating with the proper events and time, and I have a link in the `<td>` pointing to another php page for a longer description of the event. I have a foreach loop in a function that creates the calendar after getting the query from the database. I am assigning the long description row to a session variable and then printing it in the description.php page. My issue is the session variable is not changing during each iteration of the loop. Is this possible to do it this way? Was hoping I could just reference one variable to display the information, but I am doing something wrong. Any advice is appreciated!

Code in calendar.php

```
if(isset($events[$event_day])) {
                foreach($events[$event_day] as $event) {
                    $calendar.= '<div class="event">'.$event['title'].'<br>'.$event['time'].'<br>'.$event['shortDesc'].'<br><a href="/description.php">More</a></div>';
                    $_SESSION['desc']= $event['longDesc'];
                }
            }
```

Code in description.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

include  ('../dbinfo.php');
session_start();

$db=mysqli_connect($dbhostname,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname[0]); 

print($_SESSION['desc']);
//print("<br><br>");
//print("Time:");

mysqli_close($db);//Close the DB Connection

?>
```

If any more code is needed to see what I am trying to accomplish I will edit this post! And yes, I have `session_start()` on the calendar page. The session is printing but not updating for each different `event_date`.

Comment: apparently you are overwriting your variable at each interaction in the for loop `$_SESSION['desc']= $event['longDesc']`  while $_SESSION is an array $_SESSION['desc'] is not.
Try `$_SESSION['desc'][] = $event['longDesc']`

Comment: Exactly as you wrote? When I try that, it causes the calendar to fail to display. Throws `PHP Fatal error:  [] operator not supported for strings`

Comment: Since you are going to open a new page, is there a reason why there is a need to store session variable? Would you consider passing the eventid(you probably have one) to the next page using yoururl?event_id=id and then you can perform a query and print out whatever you want in a more easier way?

Comment: @MarkNg that is what I ended up doing. Could not find a way to get the session variable to change within the same month. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
if (isset($events[$event_day])) {
    $_SESSION['desc'] = [];
    foreach ($events[$event_day] as $event) {
        $calendar .= '<div class="event">' . $event['title'] . '<br>' . $event['time'] . '<br>' . $event['shortDesc'] . '<br><a href="/description.php">More</a></div>';
        $_SESSION['desc'][] = $event['longDesc'];
    }
}
```

What the code does here is to assign an empty array to $_SESSION['desc'] before adding elements to the array. The error you got saying "operator not supported for strings" is because $_SESSION['desc'] was not an array.